# Removing Escape Characters for a string

Tags: c#, string, escaping

I am having a bit of a problem with Escape characters is a string that I am reading from a txt file,
They are causing an error later in my program, they need to be removed but I can't seem to filter them out

```
  public static List<string> loadData(string type)
    {
        List<string> dataList = new List<string>();
        try
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), "Data");
            string text = File.ReadAllText(path + type);


            string[] dataArray = text.Split(',');


            foreach (var data in dataArray)
            {
                string dataUnescaped = Regex.Unescape(data);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dataUnescaped) && (!dataUnescaped.Contains(@"\r") || (!dataUnescaped.Contains(@"\n"))))
                {
                    dataList.Add(data);
                }
            }
            return dataList;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return dataList;
        }
    }
```

I have tried text.Replace(@"\r\n")
and an if statement but I just cant seem to remove them from my string

Any ideas will be appreciated

Comment: Remove the @, because @ means that you want the \ to be a character meanign instead of combingin with n and searching for newlines it will instead search for any appearances of \n in your string. That is probably why the replace funtion and ifs aren't doing what you expect them to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add the `@` Sign before a string that means you specify that you want a string without having to escape any characters.

So if you wanted a path without `@` you would need to do this:

```cs
string s = "c:\\myfolder\\myfile.txt"
```

---

But if you add the `@` before your `\n\r` isntead of the escaped sequence Windows New Line you would instead get the string `"\n\r"`.

So this will result in you removing all occurrences of the **string** `"\n\r"`. Instead of NewLines like you want to:

```cs
text.Replace(@"\r\n")
```

---

**To fix that you would need to use:**

```cs
text = text.Replace(Environment.NewLine, string.Empty);
```

You can use `Environment.NewLine` as well instead of `\r` and `\n`, because Environment knows which OS you are currently on and change the replaced character depeding on that.